# Why is ASP.NET data access so ugly?

Tags: asp.net, database

I can't figure how to make a decent website without using the asp.net builtin data controls like SqlDataSource and DataGrid. Is there a cleaner way to do this?

Comment: Did you think that maybe PHP is ugly, not ASP.NET? :)

Comment: Shouldn't be closed as the person is asking whether or not there is a way to use ASP.net without using the SqlDataSource object.

Comment: Umm, wasn't just the title of the question subjective/argumentative.  He was asking a valid question.

Comment: Not sure why this is closed. You can bind a DataSet to a DataGridView, with the DataSet loaded from a Data Access Layer. Personally, I've avoided drag-and-drop data source widgets since VB6.

Comment: why is this closed?..perhaps the user should be asking a more direct question such as "how do I connect to a database in asp.net" but is that any reason to close?

Comment: I dont know it tends to be click happy users who think just because they can close they close.  they read the title and close the thread without reading the contents of the thread.  Dont judge a book by its cover.

Comment: This should not have been closed.

Comment: Maybe the closers can inspire us why this was closed ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes there is, you don't really need an SqlDataSource, theres a reason for web.config files and stored procedures.  You're going to have to read about how to use ASP.net to connect to a database and how to pull data using parameterized stored procedures.  Look up web.config file, connection strings, and system.data.sql.

Comment: Thank you, i will search for these subjects

Comment: Additional info: Look into the Enterprise Libary http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd203099.aspx  The Hands-On Labs would be a great teaching tool for you.

Comment: @Chris Lively:  Enterprise Library is the devil.

Comment: @tsilb: I've used it successfully for years.  What do you not like about it?

Comment: Data access was a simple, elegant operation until it came along.